# How To Connect Galaxy Buds to Ubuntu

Tags: bluetooth, samsung

I recently purchased the new [Galaxy Buds](https://www.samsung.com/global/galaxy/galaxy-buds/) but was quite sad when my buds were not able to connect to my laptop which is running Ubuntu 18.04. However, my other Bluetooth device the JBL Tune 110BT was able to connect previously. I hope one of you would be able to assist me, so I can use my buds on the laptop as well.

Comment: You need to provide more information. Does it connect but no audio is played through it, or does it not connect at all? And if it does not connect, then does it show up as an available bluetooth device or does it not show up at all? Please edit your question and add that information.

Answer (score 40):

You have to enable the galaxy buds into pairing mode by steadily tapping both side of the buds for about 3 seconds or more until you hear the beeping sound. You know that it is in pairing mode if you hear a beeping sound every second. Go to Bluetooth settings in Ubuntu and you can see the Galaxy buds in the list of devices. Click the device name and you're done.

[image: pairing mode]

Comment: Anyone know of a one handed method? My left arm is broken and can't reach my ear. I'd rather not unpair them from my phone and tablet...

Comment: @DavidR. They should go into pairing mode if you place them inside the case, close it, then re-open it.

Comment: @Calixte comment should be an answer, not a comment!